# How can I have all navigation buttons centered?

Tags: html, css

I tried many ways to center all navigation buttons, I'm using `text-align: center` but it doesn't help because one of my buttons is an image and has greater height and width. I also had to resize the image because it was way too big.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: auto;
  border-color: red;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="mylogo" style="width: 100px;height: 100px"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="apps.html"><span>APPS</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[image: That's how it looks right now]
[image: That's what I want to create]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `display: inline-block;` to the  `li` elements (remove all `float: left`) and `text-align: center` to the `ul`, which centers the `li` s inside the `ul`:

If you want the two text `li` vertically centered to the image `li`, add `vertical-align:middle;` to the `li`s

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px;
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: auto;
  border-color: red;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/fda" alt="mylogo" style="width: 100px;height: 100px"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="apps.html"><span>APPS</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Your code is almost perfect but the Apps and Contact are now at the bottom of the navigation.

Comment: It's not completely clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Do you want that image and the other two `li` s vertically centered to each other? I edited my snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To horizontally align center use `text-align: center;` To vertically align you can use `display: table-cell` and `vertically-align: middle;`

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    width: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: auto;
    border-color: red;
}
nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
nav ul li a span{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><span><img src="https://www.seoclerk.com/pics/551103-1TOqFD1502285018.jpg" alt="mylogo" style="width: 40px;height: 40px"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="apps.html"><span>APPS</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Comment: Here in the code the navigation bar elements aren't in the middle of the page.

Comment: @D.B. Check the update answer. I have removed the float and used display: inline-block for li items with text-align: center for ul.

Comment: now it cuts some of the navigation bar, I think the height is to small. I can't see the full image.

Comment: well in my code snippet the image is clearly visible. Your image size must be different. Just change the size i.e. width and height and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a nice case for using a simple [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout). Set the container (`nav ul`) to `display: flex` and specify that its items have to be center-aligned. Finally, you can also indicate how those list items need to be divided in the available space. In the example below I used [`justify-content: space-around`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: auto;
  width: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 2px inset red;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="mylogo" style="width: 100px;height: 100px"></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="apps.html"><span>APPS</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, this way the website is pretty responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline` on your list item and remove your current styling for you `a` tag as this will force all items to be 100% width of the screen. Also, add `text-align:center` to your `ul` and this should center your list:

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
    background-color: white;
    height: auto;
    width: inherit;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: auto;
    border-color: red;
}
nav ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
nav ul li{
    display:inline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="mylogo" style="width: 100px;height: 100px"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="apps.html"><span>APPS</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html"><span>CONTACT</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox. It's easier than anything and it can center your navigation elements vertically and horizontally at the same time.

```css
nav {
  background:#eee;
  width:500px;
  padding:10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav ul { /* this is the magical part */
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  align-content:center;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
nav li {
  list-style:none;
}
nav a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:5px 20px;
}
a.logo {
  display:block;
  height:30px;
  width:25px;
  padding:0;
  background:url("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1b3cdae197be") 0 -500px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="logo"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```